# How can I put values of a single column in a temporary table with a select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table with data in 2 columns. The problem is that the values in the two columns represent a table with multiple columns, where the x and y-axis are in column 1 and the values in column 2.

This is a really basic select with simple joins.

What I want to get is a simple table with the x and y-axis from column one and the values from the rows from column 2. The rows have unique id's.

This is my db table:https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qSe4.jpg and this is the result I'm looking for:https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2pYL.jpg

Comment: I had pictures but am not allowed to because I don't have enough points.

Comment: This is my db table:https://imgur.com/qlwfQ7b and this is the result I'm looking for:https://imgur.com/2hbkXEr

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.col2 as XVal, b.col2 as YVal
from table as a
INNER JOIN table as b
on a.id = b.id AND
a.col1 = 'X' AND
b.col1 = 'Y'
```

In effect, you self join the table on the ID. In the "left hand side" (table a), you filter to just the column 1 being X, and in the right hand side (table b) column 1 being Y.